# Remainder Theorem - $(x+1)^{2015}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

This one just caught me without a clue.

Find the remainder when $(x+1)^{2015}$ is divided by $x$.

Assuming I don't use Binomial expansion.  What are other alternatives?

Comment: Am I allowed to use the binomial expansion of $(x+1)^2$? How about the binomial expansion of $x+1$?

Answer (score 5):

By simple application of remainder theorem,
there exist unique functions $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ such that
$$(x+1)^{2015}=(x-0)q(x)+r(x)$$

Putting $x=0$, we have that $r(0)=1$.

Required remainder is $1$.

Comment: where $r(x)$ is a constant function (of lower degree than $x-0$).

Comment: Why would I put x = 0? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: @user256670 Because you need the value of $r(x)$ as per your question. And to get that, you need to put $x=0$. Simple manipulation..

Answer (score 2):

The remainder theorem states that the remainder of a division of a polynomial $f$ by another polynomial $x - a$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is equal to $f(a)$.

In your case $f = (x+1)^{2015}$ and $a = 0$. Thus, the remainder of $(x+1)^{2015} \over x$ is $f(0) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Using division algorithm
$$(x+1)^{2015} =xq(x)+r(x), \qquad \text{ where } \text{deg }r(x) =0.$$
So substitute $x=0$, to get
$$r=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't think one would have learnt modulo operation before binomial theorem, **modulo operation** is still a way to go, i.e.

$$x+1\equiv 1 \pmod{x}$$
$$(x+1)^{2015}\equiv1^{2015}=1\pmod{x}$$

**Note:**

1. First line of expression means that the **remainder** of $x+1$ divided by $x$ is equivalent to that of $1$ divided by $x$.
2. **Property of modulo operation**:

For $a,b,n,m\in\Bbb{N}$, given $$a\equiv b\pmod{m}$$ we have
$$a^n \equiv b^n\pmod{m}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod {x}$, we have $(x + 1)^{2015} \equiv 1 \pmod {x}$.